# I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the Google Geocoder Api in conjuction with another API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm attempting to use the google api to get lat/long coordinates, and then pass those coordinates to another api that looks for doctors based on the location. Both APIS are working independently of each other, but I'm having trouble configuring them to work together using promises.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    let newQuery = new ApiCall();
    const symptom = $("#user-input").val();
    const location = $("#user-location").val();
    let locationPromise = newQuery.locationCall(location);
    locationPromise.then(function(response){
    let locationBody = JSON.parse(response);
    },function(error){
      $('.showErrors').text(`There was an error processing your 
request: ${error.message}`);
    }).then(function(result){
    let promise = newQuery.newDataCall(symptom,locationPromise);
    promise.then(function(response){
      let body = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(body);
      const output = parseData(body);
      const display = parseString(output);
      $(".output-field").html(display);
    }, function(error) {
      $('.showErrors').text(`There was an error processing your 
 request: ${error.message}`);
     });
   })
 });
});
```

I'm able to console log both results of the API, but when I try to pass the location into the betterdoctor api it isn't returning a location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `newQuery.newDataCall(symptom, locationPromise)` works, but I think you're misusing the `locationPromise`. Given that the second argument of the `newDataCall` accepts location coordinates then your code should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    let newQuery = new ApiCall();
    const symptom = $("#user-input").val();
    const location = $("#user-location").val();
    let locationPromise = newQuery.locationCall(location);
    locationPromise.then(function(response){
    let locationBody = JSON.parse(response);
    // return the result of the API call
      return locationBody;
    },function(error){
      $('.showErrors').text(`There was an error processing your 
request: ${error.message}`);
    }).then(function(result){
    // result === locationBody
    let promise = newQuery.newDataCall(symptom, result);
    promise.then(function(response){
      let body = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(body);
      const output = parseData(body);
      const display = parseString(output);
      $(".output-field").html(display);
    }, function(error) {
      $('.showErrors').text(`There was an error processing your 
 request: ${error.message}`);
     });
   })
 });
});
```

Hope this helps.